# What error do we return when parsing an invalid HTTP `Range: ...` header?

Tags: http, http-error, http-range

I'm working on a project which manually parses the `Range: ...` field. On an error, it always returns a 416 HTTP error (*Range Not Satisfiable*).

It seems to me that in most cases, like where the range is not `bytes=...` or a number is invalid, the HTTP error should instead be 400.

Have you had experience with this specific case before? What are we expected to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of an opinion-like answer: RFC 7233 discusses 416 in the context of being unable to satisfy a range request, with the strong implication that the request is syntactically correct.

> The 416 (Range Not Satisfiable) status code indicates that none of
> the ranges in the request's Range header field (Section 3.1) overlap
> the current extent of the selected resource or that the set of ranges
> requested has been rejected due to invalid ranges or an excessive
> request of small or overlapping ranges.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#page-15

Errors in request syntax or otherwise malformed still correspond to a general 400 Bad Request.

> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or
> will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be
> a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
> message framing, or deceptive request routing).

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-58

So, if the request doesn’t specify valid `bytes` ranges (currently the only registered range type) I’d return a 400.